Apache Webserver, redirect condition to a directory to list the files
I'm running Apache Webserver for windows on version 2.4.62. I've been asked to make a virtual host just to simply serve up some images from a directory. I have a folder structure of c:\foo\bar\images. In the acceptance criteria for the task I've been asked to list the files in the images directory if the requested file does not exist. So my plan was to create a rewrite condition to direct any invalid url back to the images directory, so the user can see a list of files in the directory. I also wanted the DirectoryIndex to be the images directory to avoid having to add an index.html that I don't really want. This is what I currently have in my httpd.conf file:
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8445>
    <Directory "C:\foo\bar"> 
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/.*$ images/

    DocumentRoot "C:\foo\bar\embed"
    ServerName localhost
    DirectoryIndex images/
  </VirtualHost>

I'm running into a couple of issues. Firstly, is having the images directory as the DirectoryIndex even possible? I basically want the default to just list the files in the images folder. Secondly my rewrite condition is not working as intended. To test it I changed the DirectoryIndex to a valid index.html and the Rewrite rule to go to Index.html. When I use the url https://127.0.0.1:8445/images/ it redirects me to index.html. I don't want this to happen. I want to be able to see a list of the contents in the images folder. The only way I seem to be able to get the url https://127.0.0.1:8445/images/ to list the contents of the folder is to get rid of the rewrite rule completely.
